# HTTP Methods GET (works) vs POST (does not work)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Desc**

Using a trigger, I call a function that retrieves a partial view and throws it into the place in the code
(works)

**I call this function to display table**

```
function getTable() {

    var test= t6est;
    var test2test= edhwbtest;;

    if (test!= null && test2test!= null) {


        var testFtT= daysInMonth(test, test2test);

        $.ajax({

            url: "@Url.Action("PartialTabelaEcp", "Home")",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { testFtT: testFtT, test: test, test2test: test2test},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#kartaEcp").html(data);
            },
            failure: function (error) {
                alert(error);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

and this controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(int testFtT, int test, int test2test)
        { 
             return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja");
        }
```

- I need to change from httpget to httpppost, because I need to send the data to the database

but when I change

```
$.ajax({


            type: "GET",


and 


[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult
```

to

```
$.ajax({


            type: "POST",

and

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult
```

Error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: is there any more detail on that error (turn on detailed errors if you're running locally). Can you add a breakpoint to the `[HttpPost]` action to see if it is being hit. The 500 suggests the action is being hit but something after that is breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AJAX` call would look like:

```
  var json = {
          testFtT: testFtT ,
          test: test,
          test2test: test2test
         };

  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},,
      url: "@Url.Action("PartialTabelaEcp", "Home")",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
            $("#kartaEcp").html(data);
        },
      failure: function (error) {
            alert(error);

        },
      error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

And your `Controller` method will be:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string json)
{

  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

  //Get your variables here from AJAX call
  var testFtT= jsondata["testFtT"];
  var test= jsondata["test"];
  var test2test= jsondata["test2test"];

  return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja");
}
```

Comment: serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));  || error naer Deserialize [dont get next number argument "2" ]

Comment: @krolPodGora During debugging, what values do you get in your `json` string in the `Controller` method? Make sure you are correctly generating your values on the `js` side

Comment: dataType: "json" ,?

I get an html view, so I think I must have "html" there?

Comment: @krolPodGora No, since you are sending in `json` format to the server, it should be json. The output that you are getting is a `html` so you can handle that accordingly in your function.

Comment: the controller receives data from Ajax, but I don't work with the deserializer before starting the program with the function written above

Comment: @krolPodGora What values do you get in `string json` ? You need to de-serialize this string since it is in `JSON` format. You can also use `Newtonsoft` package if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string json)  |||  in Ajax is as you wrote

Comment: @krolPodGora No, when you put a breakpoint here: `public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string json)` and debug, what value do you see in the `json` variable?

Comment: "{\"testFtT\":1,\"test\":2020,\"test2test\":31}"

Comment: @krolPodGora Looks correct. What error are you getting? You should be able to de-serialize this string using the above method.

Comment: I've already done this using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IDictionary> (json);